# get the quotient of two textbox which has an onChange event

Tags: javascript

I get the sum of ua and ub and display on tu textbox. I multiplied the ua 
and ga textbox and display on uu textbox as well as the ub ang gb . Get 
the sum of uu and a and display on tt textbox. I want to get the quotient 
of tt and tu and display on gpa textbox but it doesnt work. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

```js
    function sum(){
    var ua = document.getElementById('ua').value;
    var ub = document.getElementById('ub').value;
    var result = parseInt(ua)  + parseInt(ub);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('tu').value = result;
    document.getElementById('tu').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
    }
    function suma(){
    var ua = document.getElementById('ua').value;
    var ga = document.getElementById('ga').value;   
    var result = parseInt(ua)  * parseInt(ga);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('uu').value = result;
    document.getElementById('uu').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
    }
    function sumb(){
    var ub = document.getElementById('ub').value;
    var gb = document.getElementById('gb').value;   
    var result = parseInt(ub)  * parseInt(gb);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('a').value = result;
    document.getElementById('a').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
    }
    function s(){
    var uu = document.getElementById('uu').value;
    var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var result = parseInt(uu)  + parseInt(a);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('tt').value = result;
    document.getElementById('tt').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
    }
    function g(){
    var tt = document.getElementById('tt').value;
    var tu = document.getElementById('tu').value;
    var result = parseFloat(tt)  / parseFloat(tu);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('gpa').value = result;
    }
    }
```

```html
   <input type="text"  id="ua" name="ua" size="7" onkeyup="sum();">
    <input type="text"  id="ga" name="ga" size="7" onkeyup="suma();">
    <input type="text"  id="uu" name="uu" size="7" onchange="s();"/>

    <input type="text"  id="ub" name="ub" size="7" onkeyup="sum();">
    <input type="text"  id="ga" name="ga" size="7" onkeyup="sumb();">
    <input type="text"  id="a" name="a" size="7" onchange="s();"/>

    <input type="text" id="tu" name="tu" onchange="g();"/>
    <input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" onchange="g();"/>

    <label>GPA</label>
    <input type="text" id="gpa" />
```

Comment: The first thing to do is put some labels next to the text fields so that it is clear what each is for. Also, explain what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error in your developer console?

Comment: Where are those functions called? Do you have inline event listeners?

Comment: `document.getElementById('a')`? There is no element with the ID `a`.

Comment: You should learn to use a sensible naming approach.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using better names for your variables, functions, etc. It makes everybody's life easier. Side-remark: you don't need to use `document.getElementById()` just use its ID e.g. `var uuValue = uu.value`.

Comment: @ scott marcus I want to get the quotient of tu and tt  with onchange event and dispaly on the gpa textbox but its not working.

Comment: @PeterMader it is on second set of input. I forgot to edit it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, everything in your code works (after your edit), except that you want to get the element with the ID `gb` in the function `sumb`, but the element doesn't exist. As you have it now, your code displays the result of the value of `tt` (second in the HTML) divided by the value of `tu` (first in the HTML).

That said, I'm still not sure what you mean when you say "*it's not working*". The only thing I could think of is that you have to take away the focus from the `tu` or `tt` input element in order to make the `gpa` element display the result, because you used `onchange` instead of `onkeyup`.

As others have pointed out and as I also want to emphasize is that you should try to give your variables **meaningful names**. When you look at your code in three years, do you think you will still know what "gpa" and "uu" is?

In the following snippet, I only copied the `<input>`s that are relevant for the division. I use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event listeners (`onkeyup="sumb();"`) and made it more readable:

```js
var dividendElement = document.getElementById('dividend');
var divisorElement = document.getElementById('divisor');
var resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

function updateQuotient () {
  var result = parseFloat(dividendElement.value) / parseFloat(divisorElement.value);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    resultElement.value = result;
  }
}

dividendElement.addEventListener('keyup', updateQuotient);
divisorElement.addEventListener('keyup', updateQuotient);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dividend">
/
<input type="text" id="divisor"> <!-- <input> elements don't need a closing tag! -->
=
<input type="text" id="result">
```